# ConstraintLayout not showing properly in real device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I just created a sample project using android studio 2.3.1 for sample ConstraintLayout i made some constraints it works just fine in the preview mode but when ever i compile it to my device it will look messy 
and all my views will stick together in the middle of the activity 
I have 4.4 Kitkat device

and this is how my Contraint layout looks like in preview mode :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put constraints between the views too. Top button - Bottom Password - Top Password - Bottom Username -  and delete the constrains on sides because that will try to align every view in line.

Comment: It works for me from the first try, thanks 

But why in preview mode it shows normal even if i rotate the viewer it shows normal.

Comment: I guess it is just so you don't look track of views or something to help you with organizing views. You must not let views float around. I found this tutorial useful and maybe it can help you understand better the Constraint Layout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z53Ed0ddxgM